# make select @@IDENTITY; a long?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am grabbing the last rowid and i am doing this `select @@IDENTITY`

```
 pk = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

I get an invalid typecast bc this is int instead of long. Why doesnt this return a long? can i make it return long?

Solution for now is to use

```
 pk = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Please consider using something other than `@@identity`. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: Why do you want to return it as a long if the DB says it's an int what are you then trying to accomplish by returning it as a long?

Comment: Your solution with `Convert` is correct, although unsafe and inefficient. I belive any of the answers are better than it.

Comment: @RuneFS: the DB does not say it is an int. It is a [`NUMERIC(38,0)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @Ant_222 OP specifically says that it's an int, hence my comment

Comment: @RuneFS The OP is wrong. In *MSSQL* it is a `NUMERIC(38)`, and in *C#* it is a `decimal`. And whereas a `decimal` is not a convenient integer type, it is best to convert it into an `Int64` aka `long`.—too much confusion because people do not check their assumptions :-)

Comment: @Ant_222 there's no such thing as a mapping from mssql server type to a specific type in C# unless you are assuming a specific O/R mapper :) (Your assumption is likely right and I but it's still an assumption). However all that is irrelevant in relation to the point I was trying to make. "Why do you want to represent it as a different type than what you are provided?"

Comment: @RuneFS I meant the [*ADO.NET* type mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) from *MSSQL* to *.NET*. You question *Why do you want to represent it as a different type than what you are provided?* is very good, but you gave an incorrect answer. `@@IDENTITY` is an integer (`NUMERIC(38)`), but *ADO.NET* (according to the mapping) translates it into `decimal`, which is of course rather inconvenient. I therefore propose to convert it to `long` or `ulong` if the range of those types is sufficient (see my answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28SQL.90%29.aspx)... which is *correct* and [decimal(38,0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) anyway...

```
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS bigint)
```

However, you should note that @@IDENTITY is *also* [decimal(38,0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342(SQL.90).aspx)

This is because it must encompass any datatype that can be autonumbered such as decimal and bigint

Edit:

Apparently it's caused by [unboxing](http://forums.asp.net/t/694702.aspx). YMMV.

Comment: +1 Great! A new thing to look for learning and improving my skill! =)

Comment: @@IDENTITY has uses SCOPE_IDENTITY can't provide (ie: instead of triggers), all the "use SCOPE_IDENTITY" answers just pollute one's search how to cast @@IDENTITY.

Comment: @Serge: this is a very specialised use case that will rarely happen. If it does, it's a huge code smell why not a stored procedure for example? And we have sequences in SQL Server 2012 now too

Comment: @gbn having DML on view isn't not something rare on well designed databases. Above all if you care about vertical partitioning. And I don't see what sequences change (not that I know much about 2012).

Comment: @Serge: having DML on a view that requires a before trigger, that in turn has to pass out the new IDENTITY value should be rare. This is not well designed at all: it's obscure and fragile. Sequences allow you to preallocate values that do not require IDENTITY at all.

Comment: Downvoted, because there is no evidence whatsoever that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is for some reason more sutable for the OP's case than `@@IDENTITY`. It would be excellent if you compared their performace, for, being a function, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` may turn out slower. There is also no need to burden *SQL Server* with converting the value to the convenient type, because that can made locally (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

In your SQL query convert `@@IDENTITY` to `bigint`:

```
select CONVERT(bigint, @@IDENTITY) ...
```

Comment: don't use @@identity - use SCOPE_IDENTITY() - you'll getter more accurate results!

Answer (score 3):

SELECT CAST(@@IDENTITY AS BIGINT) maybe?

Comment: don't use @@identity - use SCOPE_IDENTITY() - you'll getter more accurate results!

Comment: @marc_s If the OP knows what `@@IDENTITY` does and uses it correctly, there may be trouble at all. In fact, I cannot imagine a sane use case in C# where `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` would make a difference—using the same *SqlConnection* from different threads or otherwise in parallel is likely a *very* bad idea...

Comment: @Ant_222 it's actually very simple: if you insert into a table with an identity column, and there's a trigger on that table that writes a row into another table - also with an identity column - the `@@identity` returns the **wrong** value - the one inserted by the trigger (into the audit table, or whatever it may be) - while `scope_identity()` returns the **correct** (expected) value - the one newly inserted into the actual data table. So it's a commonly accepted **best practice** to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the last, inserted identity value - for good reason!

Comment: @marc_s You are right about triggers, but I thought them very rare. Maybe I am wrong. If one uses triggers, one should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. I prefer to avoid them and to implement that logic either in stored procedure on in the code.

Comment: @Ant_222: the case of trigger - however rare they might be, they still **do exist** in the "wild" - shows that it is advisable to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` over any of the other methods. So just use  `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, and even if there are in fact (audit) triggers in play, even then you get back the correct, expected result - that's why I strongly recommend it over `@@identity` - just minimize your potential pain and issues by using the proper method from the get-go

Comment: @marc_s If `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is not considerably slower than I am convinced.

Answer (score 1):

@@IDENTITY returns a decimal(38,0) that can in turn be cast as any other integer type like so.

```
cast(@@identity as [int_data_type])
```

where `int_data_type` is one of the following.

**Data type**

> Range - 
>   (*Storage*)

**bigint**

> -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) -
>   (*8 Bytes*)

**int**

> -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
>   (*4 Bytes*)

**smallint**

> -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)
>   (*2 Bytes*)

**tinyint**

> 0 to 255
>   (*1 Byte*)

Consider though that it won't exceed the decimal(38,0).

Comment: its not int... it's decimal(38,0)

Comment: Thanks @gbn! I thought it was an int because of this question. But it returns an int anyway, once in code. Well, I think so. =)

Comment: Downvote, because your statement that `@@IDENTITY` is an `int` is incorrect.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller No, it returns a `decimal`, althogh it is insufficient to hold the entire range of *SQL*'s `NUMERIC(38,0)`.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller In terms of *MSSQL*, `@@IDENTITY` is a [`NUMERIC(38)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), whereas *ADO.NET* perceives it as a `System.Decimal`. If in *SQL* you `CAST` it as `BIGINT`, *ADO.NET* will perceive it as `System.Int64`. There is little sense in casting it to `SMALLINT` or `TINYINT` as it will make overflow very likely.`System.Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because ExecuteScalar returns an object.  That will be a boxed integer.  It can only be unboxed to an integer, anything else will generate a type cast exception.  The C# language specification doesn't waste a lot of words on it in chapter 4.3.2:

*An unboxing operation to a non-nullable-value-type consists of first checking that the object instance is a boxed value of the given non-nullable-value-type, and then copying the value out of the instance.*

Converting it to a long is not wise btw.  There's nothing you could do with that long that wouldn't eventually produce some kind of SQL error.  Like incrementing it yourself.

Comment: Downvoted, because `ExecuteScalar()` will return not an integer, but a `System.Decimal`. You can test it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas `ADO.NET` [translates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) `NUMERIC(38)`—the type of `@@IDENTITY`—as `decimal`, the most efficient method with the least overhead is the following:

```
long id = Decimal.ToInt64( (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar() );
```

But observe that a `long` cannot represent the entire range of *MSSQL*'s `NUMERIC(38)`.